# SDL tilemap rendering quite slow

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2, game-development

Im using SDL to write a simulation that displays quite a big tilemap(around 240*240 tiles). Since im quite new to the SDL library I cant really tell if the pretty slow performance while rendering more than 50,000 tiles is actually normal. Every tile is visible at all times, being around 4*4px big. Currently its iterating every frame through a 2d array and rendering every single tile, which gives me about 40fps, too slow to actually put any game logic behind the system.

I tried to find some alternative systems, like only updating updated tiles but people always commented on how this is a bad practice and that the renderer is supposed to be cleaned every frame and so on.

[Here a picture of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEzTI.png)

**So I basically wanted to ask if there is any more performant system than rendering every single tile every frame.**

**Edit:** So heres the simple rendering method im using

```
void World::DirtyBiomeDraw(Graphics *graphics) {


    if(_biomeTexture == NULL) {
        _biomeTexture = graphics->loadImage("assets/biome_sprites.png");
        printf("Biome texture loaded.\n");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < globals::WORLD_WIDTH; i++) {
        for(int l = 0; l < globals::WORLD_HEIGHT; l++) {
            SDL_Rect srect;

            srect.h = globals::SPRITE_SIZE;
            srect.w = globals::SPRITE_SIZE;

            if(sites[l][i].biome > 0) {
                srect.y = 0;
                srect.x = (globals::SPRITE_SIZE * sites[l][i].biome) - globals::SPRITE_SIZE;
            }
            else {
                srect.y = globals::SPRITE_SIZE;
                srect.x = globals::SPRITE_SIZE * fabs(sites[l][i].biome);
            }
            SDL_Rect drect = {i * globals::SPRITE_SIZE * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, l * globals::SPRITE_SIZE * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, 
                globals::SPRITE_SIZE * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, globals::SPRITE_SIZE * globals::SPRITE_SCALE};



            graphics->blitOnRenderer(_biomeTexture, &srect, &drect);

        }
    }
}
```

So in this context every tile is called "site", this is because they're also storing information like moisture, temperature and so on.

Every site got a biome assigned during the generation process, every biome is basically an ID, every land biome has an ID higher than 0 and every water id is 0 or lower.

This allows me to put every biome sprite ordered by ID into the "biome_sprites.png" image. All the land sprites are basically in the first row, while all the water tiles are in the second row. This way I dont have to manually assign a sprite to a biome and the method can do it itself by multiplying the tile size(basically the width) with the biome.

Heres the [biome ID table from my SDD/GDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjJyH.png) and the [actual spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELQnw.png).

The blitOnRenderer method from the graphics class basically just runs a SDL_RenderCopy blitting the texture onto the renderer.

```
void Graphics::blitOnRenderer(SDL_Texture *texture, SDL_Rect 
*sourceRectangle, SDL_Rect *destinationRectangle) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(this->_renderer, texture, sourceRectangle, destinationRectangle);
}
```

In the game loop every frame a RenderClear and RenderPresent gets called.

I really hope I explained it understandably, ask anything you want, im the one asking you guys for help so the least I can do is be cooperative :D

Comment: Instead of every single tile every frame, render them all to one texture, and then just render that texture (if they don't change, of course). Also, make sure that you're using `SDL_Texture` and not `SDL_Surface`.

Comment: Are all the 240x240 tiles visible at the same time? Hard to believe. Even on a 4K display that would result in at most 16 pixels per tile horizontally (ignoring vertical direction). Another common strategy in rendering is "view frustum culling" i.e. to not feed into GPU what's definitely not visible.

Comment: Without code we can not profile it. Only thing that is sure is that  there are usually several naive performance bottle-necks of that or other kind in it.

Comment: Since your tiles are just colored squares, I suggest constructing a single 240x240 surface/texture and rendring it with a single SDL_RenderCopy call.

Comment: @Scheff yeah theyre all visible at the same time during all times.

Edit: I'll post the code in a bit

Comment: Plz, add `blitOnRenderer` code. W/o it'll be quite hard to help. Form current state I can advise either generate a mesh with each cell represented by a quad with `drect` position and `srect` texture coordinates. Or you can try and batch all tiles of same kind to one call.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko sure thing, just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poke the SDL2 devs for a multi-item version of `SDL_RenderCopy()` (similar to the existing `SDL_RenderDrawLines()`/`SDL_RenderDrawPoints()`/`SDL_RenderDrawRects()` functions) and/or [batched](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/what-is-the-technical-definition-of-sprite-batching) SDL_Renderer backends.

Right now you're trying slam *at least* 240*240 = 57000 draw-calls down the GPU's throat; you can usually only count on 1000-4000 draw-calls in any given 16 milliseconds.

Alternatively switch to OpenGL & do the batching yourself.

Comment: Thats an actual good answer :D I looked for limitation specifications everywhere and barely found anything so far. Any tips on update based rendering? Like only rendering a tile when it updates?

Comment: @NovayaFinch: Eh, if everything's properly batched (texture atlas + big 'ole geometry buffer) you can render your entire 240x240 map in a single draw-call; if tiles change you can spot-upload only the affected tiles via `glBufferSubData()` or just re-upload the entire geometry buffer; 4-6 MiB of geometry data isn't all that much.